# cURL authentication fails with PHP/CLI, but Wget CLI and AJAX requests work

Tags: php, curl, wget

I'm attempting to access the [Australia Post API](https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/dce/reference/ValidateAustralianAddress_v1) to validate addresses, however I am not able to authorise the call via cURL with PHP or CLI.

The following Wget CLI call works as expected and returns the XML:

```
wget --user=username@domain.com.au --password=pass https://api.auspost.com.au/ValidateAddress.xml?addressLine1=31+test+street\&suburb=Adelaide\&postcode=5000\&state=SA\&country=Australia
```

And the CLI log from Wget:

```
--2014-12-16 00:33:24--  https://api.auspost.com.au/ValidateAddress.xml?addressLine1=31+test+street&suburb=Adelaide&postcode=5000&state=SA&country=Australia
Resolving api.auspost.com.au (api.auspost.com.au)... 54.66.176.138, 54.66.176.138
Connecting to api.auspost.com.au (api.auspost.com.au)|54.66.176.138|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Reusing existing connection to api.auspost.com.au:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 255 [application/xml]
Saving to: ‘ValidateAddress.xml?addressLine1=31+test+street&suburb=Adelaide&postcode=5000&state=SA&country=Australia.5’
```

However the below cURL CLI call does not:

```
curl -u username@domain.com.au:pass https://api.auspost.com.au/ValidateAddress.xml?addressLine1=31+test+street\&suburb=Adelaide\&postcode=5000\&state=SA\&country=Australia -v
```

cURL log:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.66.176.138...
* Connected to api.auspost.com.au (54.66.176.138) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: api.auspost.com.au
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user@domain.com.au'
> GET /ValidateAddress.xml?addressLine1=3 HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic auth_hash_here
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: api.auspost.com.au
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
```

Passing an 'Authorization' header with the auth hash as below also results in a 401 error.

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Basic auth_hash_here' https://api.auspost.com.au/ValidateAddress.xml?addressLine1=31+test+street\&suburb=Adelaide\&postcode=5000\&state=SA\&country=Australia -v
```

Ultimately, I need to call this in PHP (ideally via Guzzle but will take cURL if I can get it working!). Below is the PHP code I have tried with no success.

```
$service_url = 'https://api.auspost.com.au/ValidateAddress.xml?addressLine1=31+test+street&suburb=Adelaide&postcode=5000&state=SA&country=Australia';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username@domain.com.au:pass");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($curl_response);
```

I have successfully ran the call via a Chrome REST client, and can see the correct headers being sent with the call via Chrome's network inspector.

The username and password details are correct, and have verified this numerous times.

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I could get this working in PHP?

Comment: Unescape the `&`'s in `$service_url`.

Comment: @lafor Same 401 response with or without escaped &'s in $service_url (and in the cURL CLI call)

Comment: The problem might be related to the cookies - you are not using them.

Comment: @Cheery That would be it! Adding the cURL options CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR & CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE worked.